# How do I acquire all the meta-information for a particular page I am on?

Tags: debug

I am trying to customize behavior for different displays of pages; I know I can use the Template Hierarchy and Conditional Tags to accomplish this. In the process of debugging, though, I'd like to be able to access all the meta-information about a page without having to iterate through all the `is_*` functions.

Is there a way to access this meta-information without rolling my own function (which would basically iterate through all the `is_*` functions). It would also be nice if this function had other information in it as well such as page-id, author, category, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can inspect $wp_query to see the query vars and returned data, including all of those conditionals:

```
<pre><?php print_r($wp_query); ?></pre>
```